# Using the List Class contains method on a list with a data type: user-defined

Tags: apex

From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_lists.htm?search_text=List), list "elements can be of any data type—primitive types, collections, sObjects, user-defined types, and built-in Apex types."

My user-defined data type is this class

```
public class SelectOption {
    public SelectOption(String value, String label, Boolean selected) {
        this.value = value;
        this.label = label;
        this.disabled = false;
        this.escapeItem = false;
        this.selected = selected;
    }      

    @AuraEnabled
    public String label { get;set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String value { get;set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean disabled { get;set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean escapeItem { get;set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean selected { get;set;}

}
```

When you save it in your org, you will be able to run this code in Execute Anonymous Apex.

```
// test data
SelectOption california = new SelectOption('California', 'California', false);
SelectOption alaska1 = new SelectOption('Alaska', 'Alaska', false);
SelectOption alaska2 = new SelectOption('Alaska', 'Alaska', false);

// list with dups
List<SelectOption> states = new List<SelectOption>{california, alaska1, alaska2};

// list to contain no dups    
List<SelectOption> noDupStates = new List<SelectOption>();

for(SelectOption so : states) {
    Boolean stateNotInList = !noDupStates.contains(so);
    if(stateNotInList) {
        noDupStates.add(so);
    }
}    

// prints: DEBUG|(SelectOption:[disabled=false, escapeItem=false, label=California, selected=false, value=California], SelectOption:[disabled=false, escapeItem=false, label=Alaska, selected=false, value=Alaska], SelectOption:[disabled=false, escapeItem=false, label=Alaska, selected=false, value=Alaska])
System.debug(noDupStates);

// fails
System.assertEquals(2, noDupStates.size());
```

Why does this fail? I don't see anything in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm?search_text=List) about `contains(listElement)` not working with user-defined types. Is there a solution to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jagmohan's answer is right, but doesn't tell you how to fix it. `List.contains()` uses the `equals()` method of the items in the list to test whether or not it has found the item it is looking for. If you don't provide your own implementation of `equals()`, then you get a test for whether or not they are the same instance not whether or not their data is equal. So, add your own implementation like this:

```
public class SelectOption {
    public SelectOption(String value, String label, Boolean selected) {
        this.value = value;
        this.label = label;
        this.disabled = false;
        this.escapeItem = false;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String label { get;set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String value { get;set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean disabled { get;set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean escapeItem { get;set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean selected { get;set;}

    public Boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj != null && obj instanceof SelectOption) {
            SelectOption otherSelectOption = (SelectOption) obj;
            return value == otherSelectOption.value
                    && label == otherSelectOption.label
                    && disabled == otherSelectOption.disabled
                    && escapeItem == otherSelectOption.escapeItem
                    && selected == otherSelectOption.selected;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public override Integer hashCode() {
        return (value + label + disabled + escapeItem + selected).hashCode();
    }

}
```

Then your assertions come out correct.

Note: I've added an implementation of `hashCode()` as well, as suggested by Keith C. If you override one of `hashCode()` and `equals()`, you really need to override both, or you'll get unpredictable behaviour if your object is used in a `Map` or `Set`. Is it a good implementation of `hashCode()`? Well, it does the job. But, how to write an effective implementation of `hashCode()` is actually a pretty complicated question in itself.

See also:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm

Comment: The advice to [always override hashCode when overriding equals](http://programming.guide/java/overriding-hashcode-and-equals.html) applies to Apex too; otherwise a few months from now someone might add the object to a Map and get some pretty nasty results.

Comment: Fair point, I've added it.

Answer (score 1):

The following two statements create two objects

```
SelectOption alaska1 = new SelectOption('Alaska', 'Alaska', false);
SelectOption alaska2 = new SelectOption('Alaska', 'Alaska', false);
```

These objects are added to `states` list along with `california` object. There are 3 objects in the `states` list.

On this line, `contains` method checks if `noDupStates` list contains the reference which `so` variable is holding.

```
Boolean stateNotInList = !noDupStates.contains(so);
```

Both `alaska1` and `alaska2` are referring to different objects and `contains` method compares their references only, not the values contained in the properties of the objects.

That's why `noDupStates` list also ends up with 3 `SelectOption` objects and the assertion fails. The debug statement also shows there are 3 objects in `noDupStates` list.